# How to target an item inside a list element by class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

let's say we have an `<ol>` with id #ol1 and we generate `<li>` items inside it using the append method,and those li's contain an input and a button.

is there a way to target a specific list item by index number something like `document.querySelectorAll('#ol1 li')[3]` to get the 4th li (0,1,2,3) element and then select an item inside it by class ?

And if we select the button with `class=remove` how can we target the container it lies within and use `someselector.remove()` to remove it without having an id to work with,so basically how can our remove function know which `<li>` to remove? (image to explain)?

i'm looking for a pure javascript solution,however if you suggest something with jquery please include the js logic as well.

[image]

*msg to mods : i opened a new question because editing the previous one would change the subject significantly.

```js
function append() {

  var index = document.getElementById("ol1").getElementsByTagName("li").length;


  var ol = document.getElementById("ol1");
  var li = document.createElement("li");


  li.innerHTML = (`LIST ITEM <input class=input  value=this&nbsp;is&nbsp;list&nbsp;item&nbsp;number&nbsp;${index}><button class=remove>REMOVE</button>`);
  ol.append(li)
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="append()">Append</button>
  <ol id="ol1">
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you can use nth-child or `ol.querySelectorAll('li')[idx]`

But you really want to use  an eventListener on the OL and the [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method

```js
function append() {
  var index = document.getElementById("ol1").getElementsByTagName("li").length;
  var ol = document.getElementById("ol1");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = (`LIST ITEM <input class=input  value=this&nbsp;is&nbsp;list&nbsp;item&nbsp;number&nbsp;${index}><button class=remove>REMOVE</button>`);
  ol.append(li)
}
document.getElementById("ol1").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")) tgt.closest("li").remove();
})
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="append()">Append</button>
  <ol id="ol1">
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

An **alternative approach** to targeting by class is simply to access the `parentNode` of the button being clicked.

To each `button.remove` we can attach an `onclick` event listener which fires the following function:

```
const removeListItem = (event) => {

  const listItem = event.target.parentNode; // <= This is just the parentNode of the button
  ol1.removeChild(listItem);
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
const ol1 = document.getElementById('ol1');

const removeListItem = (event) => {

  const listItem = event.target.parentNode;
  ol1.removeChild(listItem);
}

const append = () => {
  
  // FIND LENGTH OF CURRENT LIST
  const index = ol1.getElementsByTagName('li').length;

  // BUILD INPUT FOR NEW LIST ITEM
  let newListItemInput = document.createElement('input');
  newListItemInput.classList = 'input';
  newListItemInput.setAttribute('value', `this is list item number ${index}`);
  
  // BUILD BUTTON FOR NEW LIST ITEM
  let newListItemButton = document.createElement('button');
  newListItemButton.classList = 'remove';
  newListItemButton.textContent = 'REMOVE';
  newListItemButton.addEventListener('click', removeListItem, false);
  
  // BUILD NEW LIST ITEM
  let newListItem = document.createElement('li');
  newListItem.textContent = 'LIST ITEM ';
  newListItem.appendChild(newListItemInput);
  newListItem.appendChild(newListItemButton);
  
  // APPEND NEW LIST ITEM
  ol1.appendChild(newListItem);
}

btn1.addEventListener('click', append, false);
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Append</button>
<ol id="ol1"></ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "is there a way to target a specific list item by index"

Yes - `:nth-child()`, so:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#ol1 li:nth-child(3)')
```

Keep in mind that `:nth-child()` is 1-indexed, not 0-, i.e. the first element is at index 1, not 0.

> "And if we select the button with class=remove how can we target the container it lies within"

Meet `closest()`, which navigates upwards in the DOM from a specific element, until a certain selector condition is met.

```
someElement.closest('.foo'); //<-- returns the nearest parent/ancestor with .foo
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to target a specific list item by index number something like document.querySelectorAll('#ol1 li')[3] to get the 4th li (0,1,2,3) element and then select an item inside it by class ?

If that means you want to always get the 4th item in the collection of all elements selected by `'#ol1 li'`, ...

**It's NOT possible using CSS:**

CSS works as follows: all parts of the selector must match the element in order for rules to apply.

`.some-class:nth-child(4)` means: it has to have the class of `some-class` ***and*** it has to be the 4-th child of its parent. If you have 100 (i.e: deeply nested) items in your document for which both the conditions are true, all 100 of them will have the rules applied.

This is because CSS does not have the concept of a collection when applying rules to an element. For every single element in DOM it goes through every single selector in CSSOM. If the selector applies to the current element, the specified rules are applied. Then it moves to the next DOM element.

---

**Using JavaScript (vanilla):**

```
const element = [...document.querySelectorAll('.some-class')][3]; // 0 indexed
if (element) {
  // first match of .other-class inside `element`:
  element.querySelector('.other-class') // first match

  // 4th .other-class inside 4th .some-class:
  [...element.querySelectorAll('.other-class')][3] 
 }
```

---

**Using JQuery:**

```
const $el = $('.some-class'):eq(3); // 0 indexed, also
if ($el.is('.some-class')) {
  // collection of all `.other-class` elements inside `$el`:
  $('.other-class', $el)
}
```

Note in jQuery you need to check if the returned result is an actual DOM element (by using `.is()`), as the returned value for no matches is still truthy (a function), leading to subtle bugs.

Answer (score -1):

Try document.querySelector ('#ol1'). querySelectorAll('li')[3]